# "/Library" directory permission denied on Mac - Python3

Tags: python, authentication, directory, copy, paste

I'm trying to create a program that copies a directory in the library directory on mac (path : "/Library"). I use shutil which works very well in other directories but not in the Library directory...

I want to be able to compile my program, so I can't run it as root.

Here is my code :

```
import shutil

def copy(src_path, dir_path):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src_path, dir_path)
        print("Success!")
    except:
        print("Impossible to copy the folder...")
        print("Failed!")

copy("/Users/marinnagy/Desktop/Test", "Library/Test")
```

I think it's because the library directory is protected and requires authentication to make changes.
Do I have to make an authentication request to the user ? Or do I need to use another method than shutil ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you tried running it as [root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)?

Comment: With the sudo command ? No I didn't, but I want to be able to compile the program with pyinstaller, so this is not a great solution for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good deal of research and many attempts, I finally managed to copy a folder into my Library directory.

On macOS, the process of writing to a protected directory like the Library directory is blocked for python program. Once compiled (I use pyinstaller), it seems to be impossible for a python application to access this kind of folder, even if you give the app Full Disk Access in the System Preferences.

So I used some AppleScript to manage this specific copy/paste task :

```
on run {scr_path, dir_path} # Run with arguments
    # Translate standard paths to their quoted form
    set formated_scr_path to quoted form of scr_path
    set formated_dir_path to quoted form of dir_path
    # Run a simple shell script to copy the repertory in the other
    do shell script "cp -R " & formated_scr_path & space & formated_dir_path ¬
    with administrator privileges # Ask for administrator privileges
end run
```

Then, in my python program, I call the AppleScript program when I want to copy/past to a protected repertory like the Library repertory :

```
import subprocess

def copy(scr_path, dir_path):
    # Use the osascript process to call the AppleScript
    # Give the paths in arguments
    process = subprocess.call(['osascript', "path/to/applescript", 
    scr_path, dir_path])
return process

copy("path/to/folder 1", "path/to/folder 2")
```

This method worked for me on protected repertories. The AppleScript run in the background and an authentication window pop in, asking the user to identify himself as an admin :
[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVRMB.png)